# Can't install package contractions

Tags: python, installation, jupyter-notebook, package, contractions

I have run `!pip install contractions` in `jupyter notebook` and it fails to install library contractions with the message show below;

ERROR:

> Command errored out with exit status 1:    command:
> 'C:\Users\tassa\anaconda3\python.exe' -u -c 'import sys, setuptools,
> tokenize; sys.argv[0] =
> '"'"'C:\Users\tassa\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-6m7bhg7o\pyahocorasick\setup.py'"'"';
> **file**='"'"'C:\Users\tassa\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-6m7bhg7o\pyahocorasick\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize,
> '"'"'open'"'"', open)(**file**);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"',
> '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, **file**, '"'"'exec'"'"'))'
> bdist_wheel -d 'C:\Users\tassa\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-wheel-jh2m54oo'
> cwd: C:\Users\tassa\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-6m7bhg7o\pyahocorasick\
> Complete output (5 lines):   running bdist_wheel   running build
> running build_ext   building 'ahocorasick' extension   error:
> Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 or greater is required. Get it with
> "Microsoft C++ Build Tools":
> https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/visual-cpp-build-tools/
> ----------------------------------------   ERROR: Failed building wheel for pyahocorasick
> ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
> command: 'C:\Users\tassa\anaconda3\python.exe' -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] =
> '"'"'C:\Users\tassa\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-6m7bhg7o\pyahocorasick\setup.py'"'"';
> **file**='"'"'C:\Users\tassa\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-6m7bhg7o\pyahocorasick\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize,
> '"'"'open'"'"', open)(**file**);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"',
> '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, **file**, '"'"'exec'"'"'))'
> install --record
> 'C:\Users\tassa\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-record-b10kt37w\install-record.txt'
> --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers 'C:\Users\tassa\anaconda3\Include\pyahocorasick'
> cwd: C:\Users\tassa\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-6m7bhg7o\pyahocorasick
> Complete output (5 lines):
> running install
> running build
> running build_ext
> building 'ahocorasick' extension
> error: Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 or greater is required. Get it with "Microsoft C++ Build Tools":
> https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/visual-cpp-build-tools/
> ---------------------------------------- ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: 'C:\Users\tassa\anaconda3\python.exe' -u -c
> 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] =
> '"'"'C:\Users\tassa\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-6m7bhg7o\pyahocorasick\setup.py'"'"';
> **file**='"'"'C:\Users\tassa\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-6m7bhg7o\pyahocorasick\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize,
> '"'"'open'"'"', open)(**file**);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"',
> '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, **file**, '"'"'exec'"'"'))'
> install --record
> 'C:\Users\tassa\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-record-b10kt37w\install-record.txt'
> --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers 'C:\Users\tassa\anaconda3\Include\pyahocorasick' Check the logs for
> full command output.

Comment: Please mention python version

Comment: I run on Jupyter with Python 3.8.5 [MSC v.1916 64 bit (AMD64)]

Comment: From [documentation](https://pypi.org/project/contractions/) it supports till python 3.6 so create an environment of it and then install it !

Comment: Thanks, I will take a look at the virtual environment for more detail.