# Not able to install contractions, pycontractions package in PyCharm

Tags: python, ubuntu, pip, pycharm

I got error while installing both contractions, pycontractions through terminal and settings on PyCharm. However I was able to install them on ubuntu command line. But it seems pycharm is not able to import packages installed through command line of ubuntu.

While installing the contraction, pycontraction package on PyCharm I got following error :

```
Collecting pycontractions
  Downloading pycontractions-2.0.1-py3-none-any.whl (9.6 kB)
Collecting gensim>=2.0
  Downloading gensim-4.1.2-cp37-cp37m-manylinux_2_12_x86_64.manylinux2010_x86_64.whl (24.1 MB)
Collecting pyemd>=0.4.4
  Downloading pyemd-0.5.1.tar.gz (91 kB)
Collecting language-check>=1.0
  Downloading language-check-1.1.tar.gz (33 kB)
Requirement already satisfied: scipy>=0.18.1 in /home/mike/PycharmProjects/sentiment-analysis/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages (from gensim>=2.0->pycontractions) (1.7.1)
Requirement already satisfied: numpy>=1.17.0 in /home/mike/PycharmProjects/sentiment-analysis/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages (from gensim>=2.0->pycontractions) (1.21.3)
Collecting smart-open>=1.8.1
  Downloading smart_open-5.2.1-py3-none-any.whl (58 kB)
Building wheels for collected packages: language-check, pyemd
  Building wheel for language-check (setup.py): started
  Building wheel for language-check (setup.py): still running...
  Building wheel for language-check (setup.py): finished with status 'error'
  Running setup.py clean for language-check
  Building wheel for pyemd (setup.py): started
  Building wheel for pyemd (setup.py): finished with status 'error'
  Running setup.py clean for pyemd
Failed to build language-check pyemd
Installing collected packages: smart-open, pyemd, language-check, gensim, pycontractions
    Running setup.py install for pyemd: started
    Running setup.py install for pyemd: finished with status 'error'

  ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
   command: /home/mike/PycharmProjects/sentiment-analysis/venv/bin/python -u -c 'import io, os, sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/tmp/pip-install-lxk5lfva/language-check_3eaf32c96573438f8c5b56e9f1c8c15c/setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'/tmp/pip-install-lxk5lfva/language-check_3eaf32c96573438f8c5b56e9f1c8c15c/setup.py'"'"';f = getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__) if os.path.exists(__file__) else io.StringIO('"'"'from setuptools import setup; setup()'"'"');code = f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' bdist_wheel -d /tmp/pip-wheel-8m60jjom
       cwd: /tmp/pip-install-lxk5lfva/language-check_3eaf32c96573438f8c5b56e9f1c8c15c/
  Complete output (35 lines):
  Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
    File "/tmp/pip-install-lxk5lfva/language-check_3eaf32c96573438f8c5b56e9f1c8c15c/setup.py", line 595, in <module>
      sys.exit(main())
    File "/tmp/pip-install-lxk5lfva/language-check_3eaf32c96573438f8c5b56e9f1c8c15c/setup.py", line 590, in main
      run_setup_hooks(config)
    File "/tmp/pip-install-lxk5lfva/language-check_3eaf32c96573438f8c5b56e9f1c8c15c/setup.py", line 561, in run_setup_hooks
      language_tool_hook(config)
    File "/tmp/pip-install-lxk5lfva/language-check_3eaf32c96573438f8c5b56e9f1c8c15c/setup.py", line 584, in language_tool_hook
      download_lt()
    File "/tmp/pip-install-lxk5lfva/language-check_3eaf32c96573438f8c5b56e9f1c8c15c/download_lt.py", line 128, in download_lt
      with closing(urlopen(url)) as u:
    File "/usr/lib/python3.7/urllib/request.py", line 222, in urlopen
      return opener.open(url, data, timeout)
    File "/usr/lib/python3.7/urllib/request.py", line 531, in open
      response = meth(req, response)
    File "/usr/lib/python3.7/urllib/request.py", line 641, in http_response
      'http', request, response, code, msg, hdrs)
    File "/usr/lib/python3.7/urllib/request.py", line 563, in error
      result = self._call_chain(*args)
    File "/usr/lib/python3.7/urllib/request.py", line 503, in _call_chain
      result = func(*args)
    File "/usr/lib/python3.7/urllib/request.py", line 755, in http_error_302
      return self.parent.open(new, timeout=req.timeout)
    File "/usr/lib/python3.7/urllib/request.py", line 531, in open
      response = meth(req, response)
    File "/usr/lib/python3.7/urllib/request.py", line 641, in http_response
      'http', request, response, code, msg, hdrs)
    File "/usr/lib/python3.7/urllib/request.py", line 569, in error
      return self._call_chain(*args)
    File "/usr/lib/python3.7/urllib/request.py", line 503, in _call_chain
      result = func(*args)
    File "/usr/lib/python3.7/urllib/request.py", line 649, in http_error_default
      raise HTTPError(req.full_url, code, msg, hdrs, fp)
  urllib.error.HTTPError: HTTP Error 403: Forbidden
  ----------------------------------------
  ERROR: Failed building wheel for language-check
  ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
   command: /home/mike/PycharmProjects/sentiment-analysis/venv/bin/python -u -c 'import io, os, sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/tmp/pip-install-lxk5lfva/pyemd_aa42532f0bbb45ce80073728273c4144/setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'/tmp/pip-install-lxk5lfva/pyemd_aa42532f0bbb45ce80073728273c4144/setup.py'"'"';f = getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__) if os.path.exists(__file__) else io.StringIO('"'"'from setuptools import setup; setup()'"'"');code = f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' bdist_wheel -d /tmp/pip-wheel-za_foj8v
       cwd: /tmp/pip-install-lxk5lfva/pyemd_aa42532f0bbb45ce80073728273c4144/
  Complete output (20 lines):
  running bdist_wheel
  running build
  running build_py
  creating build
  creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7
  creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/pyemd
  copying pyemd/__about__.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/pyemd
  copying pyemd/__init__.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/pyemd
  warning: build_py: byte-compiling is disabled, skipping.
  
  running build_ext
  building 'pyemd.emd' extension
  creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.7
  creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.7/pyemd
  x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc -pthread -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O2 -Wall -g -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -g -fwrapv -O2 -g -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wdate-time -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fPIC -I/home/mike/PycharmProjects/sentiment-analysis/venv/include -I/usr/include/python3.7m -I/home/mike/PycharmProjects/sentiment-analysis/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/numpy/core/include -c pyemd/emd.cpp -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.7/pyemd/emd.o
  pyemd/emd.cpp:23:10: fatal error: Python.h: No such file or directory
   #include "Python.h"
            ^~~~~~~~~~
  compilation terminated.
  error: command 'x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc' failed with exit status 1
  ----------------------------------------
  ERROR: Failed building wheel for pyemd
    ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
     command: /home/mike/PycharmProjects/sentiment-analysis/venv/bin/python -u -c 'import io, os, sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/tmp/pip-install-lxk5lfva/pyemd_aa42532f0bbb45ce80073728273c4144/setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'/tmp/pip-install-lxk5lfva/pyemd_aa42532f0bbb45ce80073728273c4144/setup.py'"'"';f = getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__) if os.path.exists(__file__) else io.StringIO('"'"'from setuptools import setup; setup()'"'"');code = f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record /tmp/pip-record-l59ioki7/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers /home/mike/PycharmProjects/sentiment-analysis/venv/include/site/python3.7/pyemd
         cwd: /tmp/pip-install-lxk5lfva/pyemd_aa42532f0bbb45ce80073728273c4144/
    Complete output (20 lines):
    running install
    running build
    running build_py
    creating build
    creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7
    creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/pyemd
    copying pyemd/__about__.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/pyemd
    copying pyemd/__init__.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/pyemd
    warning: build_py: byte-compiling is disabled, skipping.
    
    running build_ext
    building 'pyemd.emd' extension
    creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.7
    creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.7/pyemd
    x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc -pthread -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O2 -Wall -g -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -g -fwrapv -O2 -g -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wdate-time -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fPIC -I/home/mike/PycharmProjects/sentiment-analysis/venv/include -I/usr/include/python3.7m -I/home/mike/PycharmProjects/sentiment-analysis/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/numpy/core/include -c pyemd/emd.cpp -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.7/pyemd/emd.o
    pyemd/emd.cpp:23:10: fatal error: Python.h: No such file or directory
     #include "Python.h"
              ^~~~~~~~~~
    compilation terminated.
    error: command 'x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc' failed with exit status 1
    ----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: /home/mike/PycharmProjects/sentiment-analysis/venv/bin/python -u -c 'import io, os, sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/tmp/pip-install-lxk5lfva/pyemd_aa42532f0bbb45ce80073728273c4144/setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'/tmp/pip-install-lxk5lfva/pyemd_aa42532f0bbb45ce80073728273c4144/setup.py'"'"';f = getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__) if os.path.exists(__file__) else io.StringIO('"'"'from setuptools import setup; setup()'"'"');code = f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record /tmp/pip-record-l59ioki7/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers /home/mike/PycharmProjects/sentiment-analysis/venv/include/site/python3.7/pyemd Check the logs for full command output.
WARNING: You are using pip version 21.1.2; however, version 21.3.1 is available.
You should consider upgrading via the '/home/mike/PycharmProjects/sentiment-analysis/venv/bin/python -m pip install --upgrade pip' command.
```

A similar question is asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67363580/cant-install-package-contractions) however it's still unanswered.

I tried :

```
 sudo apt-get install python3-dev
```

But it's already in the newest version and thus it's not the cause of my problem. Hence my problem is not duplicate of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21530577/fatal-error-python-h-no-such-file-or-directory).

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bpip%5D+fatal+error%3A+Python.h%3A+No+such+file+or+directory

Comment: @phd can you point out which answer will solve my problem ? I tried "sudo apt-get install python3-dev" but it's already present in the newest version and thus it's not the cause of the problem

Comment: The error message shows you're using Python 3.7. Did `sudo apt-get install python3-dev` install development package for 3.7 or a different version of Python? Does `sudo apt-get install python3.7-dev` help?